# I am lost on this circuit analysis question, can someone help me understand how to set it up?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I do not even begin to know how to solve it, I am in my first circuit analysis course and struggling to understand the material, I just know I need to make equations using KCL, and then use those equations to solve for variables. Please help.

The equations I am using:

I1 + I2 + I3 = 0

I know I should identify the nodes. There is a node at the middle junction between the -4V voltage source and the 3 Ohm resistor. Is there a node between the left 2 Ohm resistor and the -4V source? And is there a node between the 3 Ohm resistor and the 5 Vx controlled voltage source?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is homework with no demonstrated attempt to solve it. Even if you don't know how to solve it you can at least show what you do know (e.g., set up the KCL equations as best as you can).

Comment: Retracted close vote per edited question.

Comment: The only node you need is the junction of 1 ohm ~ 3 ohm ~ -4 V.

Comment: *The equations I am using: I1 + I2 + I3 = 0* What are those currents? They're not indicated in the schematic. Instead of saying "I1 + I2 + I3 = 0" you could say that you're trying to use Kirchhof's **current law**.

Answer (score 2):

Redraw the circuit. Learn to do that as a matter of habit. Even well-drawn schematics should be re-drawn. You always learn a little something from the practice. So just do it. And never lose the habit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0ZSbe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There's a hidden ground reference not shown in the schematic. But it's not needed. All I did was assign \$0\:\text{V}\$ to the bottom wire and then immediately erased it from the schematic. It's just fine to do that. And it helps clear away the cobwebs.

Also, there is zero need to show that the current source is tied to ground, or anywhere else. It just doesn't matter. I also eliminated the \$1\:\Omega\$ resistor that was in-series with it because current sources have infinite impedance and adding another Ohm to that won't make ***any*** difference to anything. So I just shorted it out and tossed it away. It's garbage.

I re-arranged (flipped around) the series \$2\:\Omega\$ resistor and its nearby voltage source. Two things in-series like that can be re-arranged. And here, doing so makes the schematic look simpler. And so, why not?

And finally, I labeled the current through \$R_2\$ as the current you seek. It's the same current in your diagram. Hopefully, you see why.

Is this sufficiently simplified that you can solve it for \$I\$?